# Unable to map data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, map-function

I'm creating a search app for GitHub users using their API.  I'm able to fetch and console log the data I want, but when I try to map it to my List component it returns the error:

> "map is not a function".

I completed this before using a class component and a constructor, but I have been refactoring it using hooks.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ListComponent from './ListComponent';
import NavBar from './NavBar';

const GithubSearch = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const URL = `https://api.github.com/users/${userInput}`;

    const handleSearch = (e) => {
        setUserInput(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        setLoading(true)
        fetch(URL)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setData(data)
            setLoading(false)
            console.log(data);
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <div className='search'>
                <input
                    placeholder='Github user'
                    name='github user' 
                    type='text' 
                    onChange={handleSearch}
                    value={userInput}
                />
                <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>Search</button>
            </div>
                    {loading ? <div><h1>...Loading</h1></div> :
                        (<div className='list-container'>
                            {data.map(person => <ListComponent key={person.id} {...person}/>
                            )}
                        </div>)
                    }
        </div>

    )
}

export default GithubSearch;
```

Comment: That endpoint `https://api.github.com/users/${userInput}`, you're using does not return a list, i.e. https://api.github.com/users/kentcdodds

Comment: The return value of `res.json` is a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json#return_value) that resolves to a **JavaScript object** which could be an object, string, an array, or any valid data type.

Comment: `https://api.github.com/users` returns a list `https://api.github.com/users/username` returns an object

Comment: I understand it returns an object, but how can that be mapped to destructure the values need? (i.e. login, repos, followers, etc.).  I tried creating a variable to turn res.json into an array with Array.from(), but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: the `data` you get is an object containing details of a single user. without the map `<ListComponent key={data.id} {...data}/>` will get you a single `ListComponent`